# How does this code convert the decimal to binary?

Tags: python, binary, decimal

*Having difficulty to understand this code. Can somebody explain to me in a simple way.*

```
# decimal to binary
def convert(num):
    if num == 0:
         return 0
    else:  
#explain this part          
     --> return (num % 2 + 10 * convert(num // 2)) <--
        
decimal = int(input())
print(convert(decimal))
```

Comment: What part don't you understand?

Comment: @PatrickHaugh They have written a comment on that line.

Comment: @Ishan And what in there is unclear? The math? Recursion? Some specific syntax?

Comment: @PatrickHaugh The recursion, in this  line: `num & 2 + 10 * convert(num//2)` Now, I don't understand how does this line work. As I try to understand the code, the recursion gives me more confusion. What's more confusing is the asterisk. Isn't * means multiply.

Comment: Yes, it multiplies 10 with the result of `convert(num//2)`.

Comment: FWIW, the `convert` function does _not_ convert decimal to binary. It converts a Python int `num` to another int such that the decimal string representation of that int matches the binary string representation of `num`. That's quite an unnatural thing to do.